# apache failed to start in docker container

Tags: apache, ubuntu, docker

I have created a docker container with the help of dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2 && apt-get clean

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

I have created a container from it and it was running successfully. When I stopped the docker service and again started the container. The container started successfully, but the apache failed to start

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
4283f23b1785        ubuntu/webserver    "/usr/sbin/apache2..."   20 hours ago        Up 8 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   stoic_swartz
```

So, I logged into the container and checked apache2 status

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker exec -it stoic_swartz bash
root@4283f23b1785:/# /etc/init.d/apache2 status
Apache2 is NOT running.
root@4283f23b1785:/# /etc/init.d/apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2                                                                                                                                apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2 for ServerName
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Why did apache fail to start?

Comment: Why not using https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/?